# How to echo the images from a folder that start with the same id of the post?

Tags: php

My post id is the same with the beginning of the images associated with the post.
For example

a post id number may be `4625`. All the images (jpg) associated with it in the folder `imgs` are saved like this

a sequence of numbers followed by `-` and afterwards the original filename

```
4625-honda.jpg
4625-DSC_332.jpg
4625_54398.jpg
```

My question is how can I echo the images?

Is this more slow to execute rather than saving the filenames and id to a database?

Answer (score 2):

something like:

```
   foreach (glob($post_id."*.jpg") as $filename) {
    echo '<img src="'.$filename.'">'
    }
```

single file, still use glob for its easy pattern matching

```
   $my_file=glob($post_id."*.jpg");
   echo '<img src="'.$my_file[0].'">'
```

Comment: Thank you for this. In another case, what if I want to load 1 image only?

Comment: do you only have one file with the $post_id or do you have multiple but just want a 'random' one ?

Comment: The php file is in another folder than the carimgs. the file is in the main domain directory and the folder is named carimgs. How can I get them from a specific folder?

Comment: Tried this without luck `foreach (glob('carimgs/.$id."*.jpg"') as $img)`

Comment: // prevent arbitary string-inclusion into "glob" and use ABSOLUTE PATH from variable
foreach (glob(sprintf('%s/%d-*.jpg', $myABSOLUTEimgPath, $id)) as $img)